# Maven: Create a profile to deploy snapshots

Tags: maven-2, maven

I'm using Maven 3.0.3.  How would I create a profile such that if  I include the profile when deploying, deploying will only succeed if the version is a non-release (e.g. snapshot) version.  Otherwise, specifying the profile when launching the deploy should fail.

Thanks for your help, - Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using an [antrun](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) or [GMaven](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Home) execution to check the ${project.version} and fail the build if it isn't acceptable?

**Edit:** Clarification:
Antrun: [Use the antrun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html) to check ${project.version} and call the [fail task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fail.html) if it's not a snapshot version. This will fail the maven build. Something like:

```
<condition property="failme">
    <contains string="${project.version}" substring="SNAPSHOT"/>
</condition>
<fail if="failme" message="hi there!"/>
```

GMaven: There are specific instructions for [failing a build](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code#ExecutingGroovyCode-Using%7B%7Bfail%28%29%7D%7D) from GMaven. I'm pretty sure you can access the property simply using `project.properties['version']`.

Comment: According to your link, GMaven is no longer under active development and seems associated with Groovy.  I'm still not making the connection.  Please provide an example of how to do what I'm asking with the tools you suggest.  Thanks,

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time.  I went with the antrun plugin solution and it works great.